# Converting a comma delimited string to a datatable row in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to convert a string with data separated by commas into the first row of a datatable. The datatable is otherwise empty.

The datatable will then need to populate into datagridview, however nothing appears in it.

```
        Dim plt As New System.Data.DataTable 


    Dim rowData As String() = output.Split(New Char() {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim row As DataRow = PLT.NewRow()


    dataGridView1.DataSource = PLT
```

I don't get any errors, but it's also not populating the gridview so I don't know if it's just failing to populate or if the table itself never got populated from the string.

Comment: You cannot turn a string directly into a DataRow object.  If you are using OleDB, you can read the CSV into a DataTable and it will create the columns fpr you and convert rows to data

Comment: You have created a `String()` rowData, but you never use it. Why do you expect that it is in your DataTable?

Comment: @Plutonix it's actually clipboard data from another program, I copied it raw and then cleaned it up into a comma delimited format using Regex and Substrings, so it is not dealing with a .CSV file, but the string itself is CSV. Does your answer still apply in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the columns and then the row:

```
Dim rowData As String() = output.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim plt As New System.Data.DataTable()
For i As Int32 = 1 To rowData.Length
    plt.Columns.Add(String.Format("Column {0}", i))
Next
Dim newRow As DataRow = plt.Rows.Add() ' already added now '
For col As Int32 = 0 To rowData.Length - 1
    newRow.SetField(col, rowData(col))
Next
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I will save this for future projects, I have been using Excel as a makeshift datatable because I could never get it to work, but I finally get it now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable` need `DataColumn` for every item of array.

If you want add array of string to `DataGridView` then add it straight.

```
Dim rowData As String() = output.Split(New Char() {","}, 
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)    
Me.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData )
```

Comment: Got it. Suppose I want another comma delimited string to become the column names, would that work the same way but changing rows.add to columns.add?

Comment: No it is not. Check @Plutonix's comment if you reading values from a "Comma Separated File"(csv)